# calling a class from a method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning react and I am trying to call a class from a method. Here is what I have came up so far

```
class Pop extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => { this.desit("data")} }>Componant Caller</button>
      </div>
    )
  }  
  desit(data){
    <Test info={data}/> 
  }  
}

class Test extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return 
    <div>{alert(this.props.info)}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Pop />,document.getElementById("targ"));
```

Help please?

Comment: Where do you want `<Test />` to render? You could store something in `this.state` of `Pop`, change that value in the `onClick`, and then check `this.state` inside `render`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to render `<Test />` in the document? Are you trying to call the function in one component from another component?

Comment: @ross are you saying that I have access of 'this.state' of 'Pop' from 'Test'?

Comment: try returning a value from your desit function.

Comment: to make my achievement more tangible, I have updated my syntax

Comment: What you have is not wrong. `desit` will be called. But putting `<Test info={data}/> ` won't have any visible effect. That's why you gave to explain what it is that you want to achieve.

Comment: do you want to add `Test` inside `Pop` when button clicked?

Comment: basically what I want to do is pass data from `Pop` to `Test` when a button is clicked

Comment: *"basically what I want to do is pass data from Pop to Test"* You are doing that correctly. But again, placing `<Test ... />` there won't have any visible effect. **Where do you want `<Test />` to appear in your UI?** If your question is only about *calling a method*, then that what you have is correct and there is nothing for us to do.

Comment: `<div>{alert(this.props.info)}</div>` is also weird. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Felix that alert part is meant to check if I have successfully pass the data

Comment: Well, `<Test />` is never rendered anywhere, so that part will never get called. As I said, putting `<Test />` in some random location won't render it. React has to know *where* it should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a method in a separate class and trigger it from the Component?

Don't use another component, but you can create a regular class with some logic:

```
class Test
{
  test() {
    alert('success!');
  }
}
```

In the desit method, you can now invoke Test.test(), like this:

```
desit() {
  var amazingTest = new Test();
  amazingTest.test();
}
```

You could use a static method as well:

```
class Test
{
  static test() {
    alert('success!');
  }
}

// and the desit method:
desit() {
  Test.test();
}
```